# Ruby / Rails Reporting Tools?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reporting, heroku

I'm looking for a FOSS or paid framework that I can integrate into a rails application that will allow me to:

1. Create canned reports (data and graphs) and publish them to users.
2. Allow users to create their own custom ad-hoc reports based on data sets I give them. (i.e., I give them a data "view" and they can query it and slice and dice it how they want.

This needs to be something that I can install on a Heroku rails site.

Anyone have any ideas?  Does such a thing exist?  I know web based reporting solutions are often far from ideal, but I'm hoping there is a FOSS one on github somewhere that I can have the source code to and contribute to.  I just haven't found any yet.

Thanks

Comment: Will it be important to you to controll the generation of reports using ruby/rails via API calls or will it be OK to have a by-side service that can be triggered e.g. via xmlrpc or url calls?

Answer (score 4):

Although I'm not familiar with any of them, RubyToolbox has a [reporting](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/reporting.html) section for gems.

Answer (score 0):

i've seen two good gems on this topic.
 1. Compendium
 2. [Repor](https://github.com/asross/repor)